# See code for any event handler registered on any element's for any event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I'd like to know of a way in which I can select an element on a web page and see all of the event handlers (the code) for any events registered on the element.  I'd like this to include:

- the code
- even if the handlers are anonymous functions

Is this possible?  How?  I've vaguely remember hearing about a Firefox plugin which might assist...

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$(elem).data('events');
```

Watch it working: http://jsfiddle.net/paska/SRhaP/

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Event bookmarklet](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) does just that.

Comment: There is a chrome extension as well which uses the same code - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim